# When we create a primary key using hibernate we use @Id as annotation but what annotation should be used to define a foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

When we create a primary key using hibernate we use **@Id** as annotation but what annotation should be used to define a foreign key

Comment: This might help: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most often, the [@JoinColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) is use for mapping FK. If you have a link table, you need to use [@JoinTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html) instead.

Comment: Yes i accepted and implemented it was correct thank you